# When I run `git rebase main` on my branch incoming changes are from an old commit, not representing the current state of the branch

Tags: git

Edited:

When I run `git rebase main` on my current branch, in the VSCode conflict manager I am presented with current being main and incoming being the first commit made after branching, lets call it commit1. The problem is that I have made changes and committed further work since then that I would like to retain, commit3. I am expecting to manage conflicts between main and commit3 when rebasing, have I misunderstood how this works?.

I have:

- committed, pushed and pulled the current branch.
- checked GitHub to ensure changes are present.
- run `git rev-parse --short HEAD` to confirm the correct commit hash for commit3.
- run `git checkout -b newBranch` and tried to rebase.
- run `git rebase -i HEAD~3` to see if rebasing to the commit I am asked to manage conflicts with would fix the issue, it didn't.
- Tried to rebase in GitHub Desktop but have the same problem.

To clarify, I am expecting to have to manage conflicts between main's current state and commit3.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is the problem? If your changes aren’t compatible with the other branch you have to resolve the issues. And `main` is the current since your changes in the other branch are being put on top of it. So this would need much more information about what is the issue. What is “old commit”?

Comment: On the branch I am working on I have made several commits since branching from main. The first commit I made after branching, lets call it commit1, was made after completing only a small amount of work. I continued to work on the branch and now commit2 and commit3 are also part of the branch history, with commit3 containing all of the up to date code. However, when I try to rebase I am asked to merge main with commit1. I need to retain the changes made in the subsequent commits, so I am expecting to merge main with commit3.

tl:dr old commit = not the most recent commit

Comment: "I am expecting to merge main with the most up to date commit when rebasing" Meaningless. Merge and rebase are different things; you would do one _or_ the other. You have not explained what your actual purpose is. Is the point that you are about to push to GitHub to make a pull request, and you want your feature branch to be as up to date as possible?

Comment: @matt when I branched from main it included a colleague's code which failed some unit tests. That code has since been fixed and pulled to main. Now I need those changes so that my branch passes all unit tests before PR to main.

Comment: So merge main into your branch.

Comment: Extra note: you really, really need to stop using Git terms incorrectly. Every term has a precise meaning. You cannot "pull to main", for example. These terms, merge, rebase, push, pull, etc., all are very precise, and you need to use them with precision or you will be saying (and thinking) gobbledegook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rebase `your branch` against `main` all of your commits on `your branch` are effectively 'unwound' into a cache back to your branching point, and then they are replayed one by one.  As a result if there are conflicts you will resolve them commit by commit. Each one of your commits from your branch will end up getting applied to main to form the new version of `your branch`. After you resolve the first conflict you will be told to enter `git rebase continue` which will then move to process the next commit from your original branch, this will continue until all of your original branch's commits have been applied to the updated base branch.

Unless your team / workflow is to always rebase I would suggest not rebasing, but instead just doing `git merge origin/main` into your feature branch, you'll resolve conflicts once and move forward. That is the point of merge functionality.  You keep the truth true; this way in your branch history things are valid and functional just as they were as you were developing it.

Regardless of whether your teammate 'fixed' `main` or not, you would need to incorporate the changes in `main` into your branch before it can be merged into main.

Comment: Yup, I totally agree with this. Simply `git fetch; git merge origin/main` on your feature branch and you're all set. Run the tests, they should pass, and now you are ready to push to a pull request or whatever (or just keep working if desired).